# I cannot change between Windows VM and Linux Host

Tags: virtualbox

When I open my Virtual Windows Machine  I cannot leave the screen and go to my Linux system. I cannot minimize my VM window. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Any errors displayed?

Comment: No there is no error. In fact my windows is large I cannot minimize it in order to go linux.

Comment: So are you saying that you are running a Windows OS via a VM and can not get out of the Virtual Machine window?

Comment: I mean how I can minimize my virtual windows, when I start my virtual windows?

Comment: So I think that your running this in VirtualBox.... I have posted an answer below for coming out of full screen mode and scale mode. Also your right alt key or right control key (depending on configuration) should bring your mouse out of the VM.

Comment: Which linux os are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exit Full Screen mode try:

Right Ctrl (Host Key) + F

If you are in scale mode you can exit scale mode by using

Right Ctrl (Host Key) + C

If Right Ctrl (Host Key) + C does not work (there have been some issues on Ubuntu), do the following:

1) File > Preferences > Input on the Virtual Machine which is stuck in Scale Mode

2) Change or Reset the Host Key. There's no need to even save after changing the settings

3) Re-open the Virtual Machine and it should be reset!